# Relative URL of background-image causes syntax error

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular-cli

I have angular app that is embedded in existing web page.
Main page is running on Tomcat on `http://<host>/main` and Angular app is embedded on one of the subpages: `http://<host>/main/ng#/routing`.

All the resources are available at `http://<host>/main/assets/`

I want to set background-image for one of the containers but I'm unable to find solution that will work for both dev instance (started with `ng serve`) and distribution build (`ng build`).

1. This works only on dev instance but after build CSS computes it to `http://<host>/assets/bg.jpg` instead of `http://<host>/main/assets/bg.jpg` and image is not found.

```
.container {
    background-image: url("/../assets/bg.jpg");
}
```

2. When I change background-image with devtools to this:

```
.container {
    background-image: url("assets/bg.jpg");
}
```

background starts referencing valid URL but it is impossible to set this value in SCSS because it causes CssSyntaxError:

```
 Can't resolve 'assets/bg.jpg' in '<component-directory>'
```

Images referenced in this way work but background-image is not:

```
<img src="assets/bg.jpg"/>
```

Comment: can you try with just '/'? Like this-  background-image: url("/assets/bg.jpg");

Comment: @Shofol on build in running environment it references only host URL, it skips `/main`: `http://host/assets/bg.jpg`

Comment: Yes, that's why I thought /assets may work. Can you build it again using this-    background-image: url("/assets/bg.jpg");

Comment: yeah, I just did it is the same: referenced url is `http://host/assets/bg.jpg` instead `http://host/main/assets/bg.jpg`

Comment: ok. Then you need to start it from main. add main before assets. Like this- 
    background-image: url("/main/assets/bg.jpg");

Comment: You have an explained solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62619062/unable-to-use-assets-in-url-in-scss-after-upgrading-to-angular-10/62619147#62619147